# Avoid - ng-repeat to download the file each time in the loop

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

I tried to find the answer for this question but couldn't find any.

I am using **bs-popover** and i am using the popover code inside an **ng-repeat** ,

```
<div ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4.....100]">
    <a data-title="test popover" data-template="/test/test.html" bs-popover trigger="click" placement="left">Click Me for Test </a>
</div>
```

Problem is since the popover code is in ng-repeat , the file is getting downloaded in for 100 times (n times the loop executes) as seen in the networks tab of the browser

Is there any way to avoid this issue? Is it possible to load the file only on click?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i assume you are referring to test/test.html?? right?

Comment: Yes @DayanMorenoLeon the test.html is shown in networks tab - 100 times

Comment: It's actually going to be be getting the cached template each time. notice that the status code is actually 304?

Comment: Nope status code is 200 every time and not 304 :(

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps instead of passing in the file in the markup you could do it via JavaScript. So something like:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4.....100]">
    <a data-title="test popover" bs-popover ng-click="popover($event)">Click Me for Test </a>
</div>
```

And then from a controller

```
$scope.popover = function($event){
    angular.element($event.target).popover({
        template: '/test/test.html',
        placement: 'left'
    });
}
```

Comment: Sorry if i am missing something , I am getting "TypeError: undefined is not a function" and points to the line "$event.target.popover"

Comment: Sorry, can you try it with my edits? I added angular.element around the $event.target

Answer (score 0):

you should force your html into the cache get it the first time through $hhtp and then put it in  an instance of $cacheFactory.cache so the next $http calls to that url are served from there,

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$cacheFactory.Cache